# Utilize maximum space on different sizes of paper by repeating different shapes with different sizes

Tags: python, algorithm, polygon

We have a great ongoing application. In this application we provide tools for drawing svg shapes.

Now, our client had a very different idea, which is logically outside of the context of my mind.

He has the following example requirements:

- He has created three svg shapes: Knife, Teddy bear, Triangle.
- He can select any one of these shapes or multiple shapes.
- He can choose different sizes of those shapes. For, ex. he can have 24 x 24 teddy, 36 x 36 teddy and 12 x 2 knife.
- After shape selection he selects the size of paper on which he wants to print these shapes.
- He wants to repeat the selected shapes on the selected size paper such that paper is utilized at the maximum.
- I am responsible to write an algorithm for that and my algorithm should output maximum of 20 result sets to choose result from.

My mind is really out of context for developing this algorithm. I need some logic to develop this algorithm. If anyone can get me started with the repetition logic, then it will be more than what i need.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a hard problem.. here's an interesting paper I found that looks promising: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/84b0/6942a8986c6214fc88c000265c7fe7f78f52.pdf

Comment: @Blorgbeard thanks for taking time. I will go through the pdf, that you suggested.